# Display message during cookie redirect

Tags: javascript

I have a site that saves a cookie to a users computer, when they next get to the homepage they are redirected to another page via a cookie.

I have tried using jquery loading() and document.write, to display a message during the 2 seconds that the page takes to redirect but none work, right now the only events that fire are alert() functions but those stop the page from loading. wWat is the best way to do this a popup?

jQuery will not work here it has to be a pure javascript solution because the message has to display before a jQuery selector can bind to the html, such as by using document.ready

Comment: What does redirection by cookie mean? Does your server send a `Location` header based on a cookie value? Or does your JavaScript read the cookie and then redirects on client side?

Comment: Don't use `alert()`. Try modifying the html contents with `$("#some_div").html("loading...");` while your page redirects.

Comment: yes I tried this, the problem is getting it to fire before the document loads, WHILE the content is loading.

Comment: the redirect is client side with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No jQuery No Ready

```
<script>
  var cookie_name = 'cookie_name_to_check_for';
  if (document && document.cookie)
  {
      if (document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name + '=') != -1)
      {
          document.write("<h1>loading...please wait</h1>");
          document.close();
          window.location.assign('http://google.com')
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: the problem with using document.ready is that the document does not fully load, so this code will never display during those 2 seconds during he cookie redirect

Comment: thanks document.write worked, I was using document write without using an html element (in this case you used an h1 tag) this way it worked